# Canvas and Object for Coronos

Tags: coronasdk

In Corona, I am trying to write a Jigsaw puzzle like game, but the pieces are part of a video, so is there a way to run a video sequence and represent clipped segments of that video in the display objects?

Any samples would be great....

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by clipped you mean create a display object that plays a snippet of the video rather than the whole thing then yes - if you mean cut out a shape from the video the size/shape of a jigsaw puzzle piece then no.
If it's the lesser take a look at the native.newVideo() API.

Comment: Thanks Peach, I was reading your blog earlier, sad to see you leave Coronas, I may change my method here to use flip book video rather than a real video, and maybe some zoom or panning effect, using a clipping canvas method.